# When running a new project - Error:The module has not been deployed

Tags: netbeans

I have a new installation of NetBeans IDE 8.1, I tried to open and run an old Java EE EJB Module Projekt of mine. But when I run the project I get a window which says: `The project <name> uses build.properties from another NetBeans installation` with 3 options: `Build Anyway,Use this installation or Update`
I choose `Update` but got the Error:

```
pre-run-deploy:
In-place deployment at C:\Users\Name\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EJBModule4\build\classes
GlassFish Server 4.1.1, deploy, null, false
C:\Users\Name\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EJBModule4\nbproject\build-impl.xml:919: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

(The Projekt works fine on another PC with IDE 8.0.2)

The strange thing now for me is that even if I create a **new** Projekt I get the same Window which says `that the projekt uses build.properties of another Netbeans installation` -> with the same `The module has not been deplyoed` error

I tried to reinstall Version 8.0.2 but still get the same error even when I create a new project.

This is what stands on line 819:

```
918 <target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
919    <nbdeploy debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
920 </target>
```

This is my GlassFish Log:

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Jän 16, 2016 4:34:24 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFORMATION: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Jän 16, 2016 4:34:24 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNUNG: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Jän 16, 2016 4:34:24 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNUNG: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Jän 16, 2016 4:34:24 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner startBundles
WARNUNG: Can not start bundle file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@49142ddd in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\lib\templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\lib\templates\logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\config\GF_4.1.1\domain1\config\logging.properties
Information:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)
Information:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Information:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Information:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Information:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Information:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Information:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Warnung:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 87ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Warnung:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 4ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Warnung:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Information:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (11.281ms), startup services(1.419ms), total(12.700ms)
Information:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 20ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Information:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@1ba05e38 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@2532b351.
Information:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
Warnung:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 8ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Warnung:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 25ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Schwerwiegend:   Archive type of C:\Users\Name\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EJBModule3\build\classes was not recognized
Information:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://Name-PC:8686/jndi/rmi://Name-PC:8686/jmxrmi
Information:   Server shutdown initiated
Information:   Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@1ba05e38 from service registry.
Information:   FileMonitoring shutdown
Information:   JMXStartupService: Stopped JMXConnectorServer: null
Information:   JMXStartupService and JMXConnectors have been shut down.
Information:   JdbcRuntimeExtension,  getAllSystemRAResourcesAndPools = [GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool]
Completed shutdown of Log manager service
Information:   Shutdown procedure finished
Completed shutdown of GlassFish runtime
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9009
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Jän 16, 2016 4:36:48 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFORMATION: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Jän 16, 2016 4:36:48 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNUNG: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Jän 16, 2016 4:36:48 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNUNG: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Jän 16, 2016 4:36:48 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner startBundles
WARNUNG: Can not start bundle file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@3b03bd60 in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\lib\templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\lib\templates\logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\config\GF_4.1.1\domain1\config\logging.properties
Information:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)
Information:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Information:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Information:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Information:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Information:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Information:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Warnung:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 133ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Warnung:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Warnung:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 8ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Information:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (11.491ms), startup services(1.380ms), total(12.871ms)
Information:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 31ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Information:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@3a230001 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@72725ee1.
Information:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
Warnung:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Warnung:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 10ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Schwerwiegend:   Archive type of C:\Users\Name\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EJBModule3\build\classes was not recognized
Information:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://Name-PC:8686/jndi/rmi://Name-PC:8686/jmxrmi
Schwerwiegend:   Archive type of C:\Users\Name\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EJBModule3\build\classes was not recognized
Schwerwiegend:   Archive type of C:\Users\Name\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EJBModule4\build\classes was not recognized
```